# Deleting table rows older than x days in PostgreSQL database

Tags: python, postgresql, truncate

This question has been asked and answered before, but I am getting a syntax error with prior answers. Perhaps I am missing something?

```
query = "DELETE FROM currentvoltage WHERE timestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY))"
cursor.execute(query)
```

`currentvoltage` is table

`timestamp` is row with timestamp in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:ffff`

Getting

> 42601 syntax error "at or near" the "1" for 1 Day

EDIT:

After everyone's assistance, the following was used.

```
query = "DELETE FROM {} WHERE timestamp < NOW() - INTERVAL '{} DAY'".format(tableName, truncate)
cursor.execute(query)
```

*note: I am pulling the table name and the interval from global variables*

Comment: Proper syntax is `INTERVAL '1 day'` (notice the quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Put `1 day` in quotations (`'`)

```
INTERVAL '1 DAY'
```

So finally

```
query = "DELETE FROM currentvoltage WHERE timestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW() - INTERVAL '1 DAY'))"
```

Note that there is no function `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` & `DATE_SUB` in PgSQL

Comment: That's not the only error. There is also no `unix_timestamp()` or `date_sub()` function in Postgres

Comment: Between your initial post and the comment, I got it to work. Much appreciated good sir.

Comment: @BabaZuri please paste the final query